# Can I use my android's wifi to let another device to connect it through wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, wifi-hotspot

Im using a terminal-based environment, but connecting to the internet requires a browser-based authentication. Can I use my Android device as a work-around, connecting it to that WiFi and then establishing an "authentification-free hotspot" to use from my computer? My thoughts were:

1. Suppose I have an android phone can access internet through wifi-A.
2. I want my computer to connect to the internet, however it can't direct connect to wifi-A because the computer is using a terminal environment, it can't access to the browser based login system of that wifi.
3. Can I create a WiFi hotspot wifi-B using the phone, to share the internet with my computer? Note that the phone has internet access because it already connected to wifi-A.

In short, can I create a wifi hot spot using phone, but the phone has already connected to another wifi.

Comment: In theory this would be possible, if you have a dual band phone... You could use the 2.4Ghz band to connect to the WiFi network, and use the 5Ghz band to act as a hotspot and connect your device, or vise-versa. Actually implementing it could be interesting though since Android isn't designed to work that way. You would probably have to code it yourself with source from a custom ROM, I don't know of any implementations at this time. So the answer, for all practical purposes, would be no.

Comment: @acejavelin yet I am still a practical man ;)

Answer (score 0):

No; your phone can only connect to one wifi at a time. (Unless you add a usb-otg AP and write some code to make it work.) Although there are multi band wifi chips in phones it's unlikely the driver has the liberty to make the hardware work that way and writing your own driver is not practical anyway.

A more simple solution is to use [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) on your (non-android) computer in the place of a web browser but the details of that are better left to [stackoverflow](https://www.google.ca/search?q=curl%20login%20-php%20site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: curl? the web based login interface can be used via curl? I don't believe that...

Comment: Can you login your facebook account using curl?

Comment: I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. If the WiFi chip in your phone is connected to one host (mostly your router), it can't be used as repeater.

Comment: That's basically the same as what [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/155038/16575) says, but doesn't add to it?